# Existence solution pendulum equation using the contraction principle

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

How can I prove that the differential equation $\ddot{x}(t)=-(g/\ell)\sin (x(t))$ must have a solution by using the [contraction principle (by Banach)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Statement).

The numbers $g$ and $\ell$ are fixed constants and the initial conditions are $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot x(0)=\omega_0$, where $x_0$ and $\omega_0$ are real constants.

According to my textbook on ODE it is possible, but since I am an engineer, I don't know how to formally prove this.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to proof that any ODE which is of the form
$$\dot{x}=f(x) \ \ \ \ \ \   x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
$$x(t_0)=x_0$$
or even for a non-autonomous system (i.e. the right side depends explicitly on time), under some assumptions, (Lipschitz continuity of f with respect to x and perhaps something else(boundedness)). The idea is that the equivalent integral equation
$$ x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\delta} f(x(t))dt $$
can be written as a fixed point problem by takin $$\varphi(x(t))=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\delta} f(x(t))dt $$
and prove that $\varphi^n$ is a contraction with the uniform norm, since the space of continuos functions is complete with that norm there must exist a solution to the original problem 
for more detail you can check the book 
 *Lectures on ordinary differential equations* by J. Sotomayor (originally in portuguese) 
Because your original problem fulfill those conditions, it must have a solution

Comment: It might help to mention that the theorem is called the Picard-Lindelof theorem. It is an easy theorem to look up online.